# Use the CsScript when you run the program for the calculation of the formula or the implementation of a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

my program requires a dynamic approach to the implementation of a formula, a method proposed is that the formula parameters in a table, and I use them in the application, the other suggested the use of **CsScript**. I don't have experience in the use of **CsScript**. What a way to do this I use the ?